# What causes my code to inflate text file size?

Tags: python

I've written a Python program to go through the text files in a directory and create new versions of each one with added line numbers. Here is the relevant function in the program:

```
def create_lined_ver(filename):
    new_text = []

    with open(filename + ".txt", "r+") as f:
        text = f.readlines()
        for (num, line) in enumerate(text):
            new_text.append("[{0}]: ".format(num) + line)

    with open(filename + "_lined" + ".txt", "a+") as f:
        for line in new_text:
            f.write(line)
```

To test it, I ran it on a batch of text files, and then, out of curiosity, ran it again (adding a second set line numbers to the already numbered files). I noticed that each time I ran the program, the file size of the newly created files were much larger than they should have been for adding ~5-6 characters per line. The file sizes were jumping from 150 KB (original) to 700, 1800, and then 3000 KB for each subsequent run.

What's causing the file sizes to increase so much?

Comment: Looks like you've opened the files in append mode

Comment: You're appending. Does the target file already contain anything?

Comment: Have you even taken a look at the contents of the files...?

Comment: @cricket_007 Is there a difference between append mode and write mode if each file is being newly created anyway? There is no existing target file before the program is run.

Comment: @Rawing Yes. There's nothing out of the ordinary about them that I can immediately tell.

Comment: "There is no existing target file before the program is run" -- there is on the second and all subsequent runs!

Comment: You've not specified that the files don't already exist. All you said was that the size grows, which tells us you're appending, not overwriting

Comment: @DavidConrad Wait, you are absolutely correct.

Comment: Also, as your file size increases, `for (num, line) in enumerate(f):` would be better than using `readlines()`

Comment: But `file_lined.txt` is also appended from `file.txt`!

Comment: @cricket_007 AHHHH. It took me a few seconds after I sent my reply for it to click in my head what you two were saying. That makes perfect sense, thank you both so much. I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out, in the comments, you are appending to the lined version every time you run the code. Instead try:

```py
def create_lined_ver(filename):

    with open(filename + ".txt", "r") as f:
        text = f.readlines()

    new_text = ["[{0}]: ".format(num) + line for (num, line) in enumerate(text)]

    with open(filename + "_lined" + ".txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(''.join([new_text]))
```

Answer (score 2):

In line #9, you open the file with the "a+" flag.  This makes the file available for appending and reading.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/python-open-built-in-function-difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r) for a description of the different modes of the open command.  By opening the file in "w" mode, you will write over the existing file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to be using lists or appending to files.

You're looking  for something like this.

```
def create_lined_ver(filename):
    with open(filename + ".txt") as f_in, open(filename + " _lined.txt", "w") as f_out:
        for num, line in enumerate(f_in):
            f_out.write("[{}]: {}\n".format(num,  line))
```

Comment: This is positively beautiful. I didn't even know that you could have multiple context managers open at once, or enumerate the file handle object directly.

Comment: I believe you mean Positively Pythonic ;)